# Filter every JAX-RS resources of an application with a single JsonView 

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jackson

Jackson 2.0 allows to filter JAX-RS resources with a `@JsonView`.

The following example shows a way to ignore people's age in a resource response.
Unfortunately, every JAX-RS method has to be annotated with `@JsonView`.

```
public class View {
  public static class Public {}
  public static class Private {}
}

public class People {
  @JsonView(View.Public) String name;
  @JsonView(View.Private) int age;
}

@Path("/people")
public class PeopleResource {
  @GET
  @JsonView(View.Public)
  public List<People> get() {
    return peoples.get();
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/id")
  @JsonView(View.Public)
  public People get(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    return people.get(id);
  }
}
```

The only way that I've found to globally filter an application resources is by using a MixIn.

```
public class PeopleMixIn {
  @JsonIgnore int age;
}

@Provider
public class ObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
  private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

  public ObjectMapperProvider() {
    mapper.addMixInAnnotations(People.class, PeopleMixIn.class);
  }

  public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) { return mapper; }
}
```

Is there a way to configure Jackson's ObjectMapper with a JsonView? Or applying a filter to every method of a resource/application?

Comment: Is your aim just to hide some attributes in the response?

Answer (score 1):

You could sub-class Jackson JAX-RS provider, which is piece of code that handles Resource annotations. Or you can use `StreamingOutput` to manually use `ObjectWriter`, where you can specify view to use on per-call basis.

With 2.0, the goal is to reduce state that `ObjectMapper` has, since changing that state can not be done in thread-safe way, whereas `ObjectWriter` is fully thread-safe due to immutable nature. But JAX-RS providers do not yet use `ObjectWriter` / `ObjectReader`.

Another idea: you could file a Request For Enhancement (RFE) for [Jackson JAX-RS provider](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/issues?direction=desc&sort=created&state=open), to add such feature ("setDefaultView()"?). This would seem like the best solution for your use case? And implementation should be quite simple, so this could go in 2.1.0 release that should be out in a few weeks.

Comment: I've submit [this RFE](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/issues/15) following your suggestion. Thanks.